# Fix "The value for a v-bind expression cannot be empty."

Tags: python, django, vue.js

I am a beginner of Vue.js developing.
I have just built a new project with Python + Django + Vue
I faced this issue :

> The value for a v-bind expression cannot be empty. Found in "v-bind:"
>   My Vue code is this: (testdjango.vue)

```
<template>
<div id="mineapp">
{{msg}}
    <form @submit.prevent ="submitNote">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="formData.title"/>
        <label>Content</label>
        <textarea v-model="formData.content"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <h1>All Notes</h1>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(note, index) in notes" : key="index">
            <h3>{{note.title}}</h3>
            <h5>Created on{{note.created}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.content}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> index.js code:

```
export default{
fetchNotes(method, params, data){
if(method ==='post'){
  return ajax('api/notes/', method,{data})
} else{
  return ajax('api/notes/', 'get', {})
}


function ajax(url,method,options){
if(options !== undefined){
    var{params=[], data={}} = options
} else{
    params = data = {}
}
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
axios({
url,
method,
params,
data
}).then(res => {
resolve(res)
}, res=>{
reject(res)
})
```

I hope somebody will help to fix this issue. thanks...

Comment: You have a space between the `:` and `key` on the `<li>`.

Comment: Where are you mounting the Vue.js instance? `new Vue({ ... })`? You need to set the `formData` variable in the component.

Comment: thanks! I solved out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space between your `:` and `key` on your `<li>`tag. It would be nice to use a linter to avoid this kind of problems, they are simply avoided by using a linter and you don't waste so much time in this little problems. I recommend using Eslint https://eslint.org/